# длина зашифрованного текста в AES/CBC алгоритме

Tags: java, криптография, aes

Подскажите, как я могу получить длину зашифрованного ключа 192 символа?
потому как я получаю 416..

```
private static byte[] iv = "0000000000000000".getBytes();

public static String encrypt(String content, String key) throws Exception {
    byte[] input = content.getBytes("utf-8");
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] thedigest = md.digest(key.getBytes("utf-8"));
    SecretKeySpec skc = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
    int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
    ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary (cipherText);
}
```

Comment: Приветствуем на ruSO. Уточните пожалуйста длина чего у вас 416 - из вашего кода не очень понятно о чем идет речь. О `cipherText` (его длина зависит от `content`) или `key` или что-то третье?

Comment: у меня длина content 192 символа также у меня есть мой ключ (key) длина которого 32 по правильному как Вы говорите зашифрованный ключ должен получится такой же длины как и content, но почему-то по длине они разные..

Comment: 416 это длина шифрованного ключа с помощью предоставленного метода

Comment: Не путайте ключ и текст у вас речь идет о шифротексте/тексте, но не о ключе. Ключ в ASE-256 всегда равен 16 байтам

Answer (score 0):

Вот что у вас происходит.

1. Алгоритм AES-256 (то есть длина блока 16 байт)
2. Применяется алгоритм выравнивания длины блоков PKCS5, который прибавляет к исходному тексту длиной 192 байта еще 16 байт (вернее округляет вверх до кратных 16 байтам, иначе CBC не будет работать)
3. Итого получается у вас 208 байт, который шифруются в те же самые 208 байт
4. Далее эти 208 байт вы переводите в HEX, который представляет 1 байт 2-мя байтами в ASCII - итого и получаем 416 байт

Длина ключа не играет роли...

Comment: Подскажите, как можно этого избежать и получить на выход строку длиной 192 символа??

Comment: Вы не понимаете, это примерно то же самое что вы будете требовать, чтобы в байте было не 8 битов, а скажем 9. Блочный алгоритм с CBC работает именно так - длина текста должна быть кратна длине блока, а для этого нужно применять алгоритм выравнивания блоков, который и дает лишние 16 байт.

Comment: Впрочем можно попробовать `aes/cbc/nopadding` - но если длина текста не будет кратна 16 байтам - то будет ошибка

Comment: Попробовал с aes/cbc/nopadding, теперь длина 256

Comment: Может я что-то не так делаю??